# Session ID is null in Page_OnLoad event in ASP.net Webform

Tags: asp.net, session, webforms

We are required to control the number of users accessing our website.
Recently, we observed some exceptions thrown about the following codes (in the page on load event):

```
string sid = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
bool exist = lst.Any(v => v.Equals(sid));
```

The lst is a list of string, which is stored in Application variable. If the session ID does not exist in the list, it will be added to the list. The exception occurs on the line bool exist = lst.Any(v => v.Equals(sid));
More over, the list is also used in the Session_End event:

```
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Lock();
    List<string> lst = (List<string>)Application["ApplicationUserCount"];
    if (lst.Any())
        lst.RemoveAll(v => v.Equals(Session.SessionID));
    Application["ApplicationUserCount"] = lst;
    Application.UnLock();
}
```

Some logs show exception on the line lst.RemoveAll(v => v.Equals(Session.SessionID));

As the page on load event throw exceptions on the 2nd row of the code snip instead of the 1st row. So the session should not be null, otherwise the 1st row should throw exception. Thus some values with session ID equals to null is added to the application variable (the list), which makes the exception to happen.

We really cannot image how come the session is not null but the session ID is null. The application variable is used only in page on load and session end events. Session will be cleared in some pages, but session ID will not be affected.

Does anyone has idea why session ID is null?

Comment: What if Application.Lock(); and Application.UnLock(); are removed from the Session_End event? Collection of object is modified exception is thrown. Will it make the values stored in the Application variable to be null?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `Application["ApplicationUserCount"]` is filled when `Session_End` is called? And how is this guaranteed?
There is no null-check, so `.Any()` could be called on a non initialised object.